# Server request made using anchor <a> tag now showing up in Network tab in Developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I am calling using an anchor tag to trigger a file download from a server using following code

```
downloadFileUsingAnchor (requestUrl) {
    const a = document.createElement('a')
    a.style.display = 'none'
    a.href = requestUrl
    a.download = 'logs.zip'
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click()
    document.body.removeChild(a)
  }
```

On clicking of the button, file download starts but the Network tab doesn't show the request going to the server.

I don't have any filters set on Network tab either.

[image]

I was expecting any call to the server will show up in the Network tab, why is the anchor tag request ignored?

Comment: Well, it shows up in the browser's download list instead…!?

Comment: The download starts in a while (as server does some processing, collecting and zipping file in this case). So there is no way to know if the request went thru in the meantime. Also, the download request show up in network tab in case of ajax/fetch request, the download files will show up in browser's download in this case too.

Comment: Do normal non-Javascript-invoked downloads show up in the network tab? Do downloads invoked through right-click and "Download as…" show up in the network tab? In my browser they don't. And this is this same kind of download.